# How can I display my checkbox choices horizontaly with bootstrap theme for Symfony?

Tags: symfony, checkbox, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a small form with two checkboxes and one submit button that I want to display using Bootstrap. Each of my checkboxes has 14 choices with very short labels.
My form:

```
$builder
    ->add('banks', 'entity', array(
                'class'         => 'AppBundle:Bank',
                'property'      => 'name',
                'multiple'      => true,
                'expanded'      => true,
                'required'      => false,
                'label'         => 'Banques',
          ))
    ->add('companies', 'entity', array(
                'class'         => 'AppBundle:Company',
                'property'      => 'name',
                'multiple'      => true,
                'expanded'      => true,
                'required'      => false,
                'label'         => 'Sociétés',
          ))
    ->add('search','submit', array('label'         => 'Filtrer'))
    ;
```

My view:

```
{% form_theme form 'bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig' %}
{{ form_start(form) }}

{{ form_row(form.banks) }}
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="check_banks">Cocher toutes les banques</button>
{{ form_row(form.companies) }}
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="check_companies">Cocher toutes les sociétés</button>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Should I try to find bootstrap form theme file and edit it or is there a more straightforward solution?

Comment: Do you use the [`bootstrap_3_horizontal_layout.html.twig`](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-bootstrap-form-theme) file?

Comment: @Sandeep Kushwah I'm using` {% form_theme form 'bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig' %}`. I edited my question. I've tried with the horizontal theme but the result is the same (the checkbox choices are displayed in a column).

Comment: could you please update your question with the screen shot of your current output

Comment: @Roubi : Use this layout `{% form_theme form 'bootstrap_3_horizontal_layout.html.twig' %}`. Please let me know if it works

Comment: @Sandeep Kushwah As I said in my first comment, I've tried this already. The only thing it does is displaying the label next to field, but the checkboxes stay piled one on top of the other.

Comment: try keeping it just above the checkbox form

Comment: I found a solution. To indicate Bootstrap you want inline checkboxes, you must add the class "checkbox-inline" to the field. But this doesn't work with Symfony Bootstrap form theme, that must be modified.
It looks like the class doesn't propagate itself down to the checkbox_widget block. So in bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig, I now have:
`{% block checkbox_widget -%}
    {% set parent_label_class = parent_label_class|default('') -%}
        {{- form_label(form, null, { widget: parent() }) -}}
{%- endblock checkbox_widget %}`

Comment: And in `{% block checkbox_radio_label %}`, after `{% if widget is defined %}` I've added
`{% set label_attr = label_attr|merge({class: (label_attr.class|default('') ~ ' checkbox-inline')|trim}) %}`
Fixing the bug that prevents the label class "checkbox-inline" from appearing in the checkbox widget would be nicer though.

Answer (score 4):

It is enough to add this code to options of field

```
   'label_attr' => array(
       'class' => 'checkbox-inline'
   )
```

for check-boxes and this

```
   'label_attr' => array(
       'class' => 'radio-inline'
   )
```

for radio. There is result:

[image: example_of_usage]

Answer (score 1):

Check your version of *bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig*. Older versions are bugged and must be changed as follow:

```
{% block checkbox_widget -%} {# INLINE FIXED !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! #}
    {% set parent_label_class = parent_label_class|default(label_attr.class|default('')) -%}
    {% if 'checkbox-inline' in parent_label_class %}
        {{- form_label(form, null, { widget: parent() }) -}}
    {% else -%}
        <div class="checkbox">
            {{- form_label(form, null, { widget: parent() }) -}}
        </div>
    {%- endif %}
{%- endblock checkbox_widget %}

{% block radio_widget -%} {# INLINE FIXED !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! #}
    {% set parent_label_class = parent_label_class|default(label_attr.class|default('')) -%}
    {% if 'radio-inline' in parent_label_class %}
        {{- form_label(form, null, { widget: parent() }) -}}
    {% else -%}
        <div class="radio">
            {{- form_label(form, null, { widget: parent() }) -}}
        </div>
    {%- endif %}
{%- endblock radio_widget %}
```

Then in your form, simply add

```
->add('fruits',          ChoiceType::class, array(
                                    'required' => true,
                                    'choices'  => $this->getFruits(),
                                    'multiple' => true,
                                    'expanded' => true,
                                    'label' => "Fruits ",
                                    'label_attr' => array('class' => 'checkbox-inline')
                                    ))
```